# Проверка звука в webrtc + docker

Tags: docker, webrtc, fingerprint

Сейчас я проверяю звук следующий образом:
2 физических компьютера
На обоих стоит виртуальный аудиокабель для трансляции звука с микрофона на колонки и наоборот

Через selenium + chromedriver:
С комп1 совершаю звонок через вебртс на комп2 и воспроизвожу аудиофайл
На комп2 в вебртс звонке получаю этот звук и записываю в wav файл

записываю звук через JavaSoundRecorder 
через musicg.fingerprint сравниваю полученный wav с эталоном

Вопрос, как это перенести в докер, чтобы 1 контейнер = как будто 1 физическая машина в которой есть виртуальный микрофон и виртуальные колонки и + возможность воспроизводить и записывать звуки

При этом мне не подходит вариант когда используются аудиодевайсы хоста. И мне не нужно на хосте слышать что играет в докер контейнере

И мне хотелось бы например запусттиь 2 контейнера, и чтобы между ними произошел звонок через webrtc

через pulseaudio и примеры в интернете я научился воспроизводить через колонки хоста звук из докер контейнера, но это не то что мне нужно.

Или все же идти по пути полноценных виртуальных машин, типа VirtualBox ?

Основная задача которую я хочу решить, чтобы физически достаточно было одного компьютера для эмуляции 5 пользователей например

Answer (score 0, accepted):

chromedriver нужно было запускать без use-fake-ui-for-media-stream
а разрешение на микрофон нужно прописывать в логфайлах браузера
тогда ок